# Problem installing visual studio service pack on Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-7

I recently  installed  Windows 7, then installed Visual Studio 2008. 
I would like to install SP1 for Visual Studio in order to use MVC but I got an error.

I found an answers on SO that suggested a certain patch. I anstalled the patch but still have a problem, see a [screenshot here](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1254688066049379000.jpg).

What to do now?

Comment: Finally i Solve my Problem for use of MVC but icant install of sp1,
i think i must install windows again for resolve problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Finally found Problem And Solution

in the error log of windows vista refer error to network and disk error

then i copy all file from vs sp1 image to my hard disk and then disable network connection and it install successfully

special thanks  friends

Answer (score 0):

That's a very weird error. Is this just a stock Windows 7 install? Any other weird errors occurring? It could be a corruption in memory or on disk...

Comment: At First Time Error Was Another Things After install A patch this error accure

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I got this while trying to do the exact same thing--was even going to build an MVC app.  The solution was to uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio.